# Change CheckBox status on Edit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a dataform with a checkbox:

```
<dataform:DataField Label="Notify" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0">
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding notify, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToIntConverter}}" />
```

What I want to do is when a user edits the item, the checkbox will be set to unchecked.

Is there a way I can do this?

I tried changing the `IsChecked` to `False` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to set the Checkbox to false? Are you sure you've done the `Checkbox.IsChecked = false;` in the right method? I'm not sure how this works with a binding though.

Comment: Instead of the binding, I used `<CheckBox isChecked="False" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to, since it's binded to a database, simply modify the value in the Db after the task is completed.

I'd like to add that the checkbox is a flag for a task that will notify/e-mail users when it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.. in the `xaml` file

```
<s:SurfaceCheckBox x:Name="name" 
 Content="what!?"
 IsChecked="False" 
 Checked="todo" 
 unchecked="todo"/>
```

and the method you check if the box is checked or not like this

```
( bool )name.IsChecked
```